# C++ Opengl Lighting doesnt work

Tags: c++, opengl, lighting

I've already searched for the solution, but none worked.
I have already inited the Lighting and all but the objects stay unlit.

When i download examples they work but when i try to enable lighting on mine it
doesnt work.

Here is the code:

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glm\gtx\transform.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <GL\glut.h>

#include "Camera.h"

#define windowWidth 1024
#define windowHeight 620
#define CAMERA_SPEED 0.1

GLFWwindow* Window;
CCamera Camera;

bool aPressed = false;
bool dPressed = false;
bool wPressed = false;
bool sPressed = false;
bool ePressed = false;
bool qPressed = false;
bool spacePressed = false;

static void keyEvent(GLFWwindow* window_, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    if(key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(Window, GL_TRUE);

    if(key == GLFW_KEY_A && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        aPressed=true;
    if(key == GLFW_KEY_D && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        dPressed=true;
    if(key == GLFW_KEY_W && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        wPressed=true;
    if(key == GLFW_KEY_S && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        sPressed=true;
    if(key == GLFW_KEY_E && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        ePressed=true;
    if(key == GLFW_KEY_Q && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        qPressed=true;
    if(key == GLFW_KEY_SPACE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        spacePressed=true;

    if(key == GLFW_KEY_A && action == GLFW_RELEASE)
        aPressed=false;
    if(key == GLFW_KEY_D && action == GLFW_RELEASE)
        dPressed=false;
    if(key == GLFW_KEY_W && action == GLFW_RELEASE)
        wPressed=false;
    if(key == GLFW_KEY_S && action == GLFW_RELEASE)
        sPressed=false;
    if(key == GLFW_KEY_E && action == GLFW_RELEASE)
        ePressed=false;
    if(key == GLFW_KEY_Q && action == GLFW_RELEASE)
        qPressed=false;
    if(key == GLFW_KEY_SPACE && action == GLFW_RELEASE)
        spacePressed=false;
}

int main()
{
    if(!glfwInit())
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    Window = glfwCreateWindow(windowWidth, windowHeight, "3D 2.0", NULL, NULL);

    if(!Window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    glClearColor (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    GLfloat light_ambient[] =
    {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0};
    GLfloat light_diffuse[] =
    {1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0};
    GLfloat light_specular[] =
    {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
/* light_position is NOT default value */
    GLfloat light_position[] =
    {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0};

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, light_ambient);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, light_diffuse);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, light_specular);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position);

    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(Window);
    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    glfwSetKeyCallback(Window, keyEvent);

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(Window))
    {
        glViewport(0, 0, (double)windowWidth, (double)windowHeight);

        //glClearColor(0.0,0.5,1.0,1.0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX);
        glLoadIdentity();


        gluPerspective( 90, (double)windowWidth / (double)windowHeight, 0.1, 100 );
        gluLookAt(0,0,5,0,0,-0.1,0.0,1.0,0.0);



        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX);


        if(aPressed)
            Camera.StrafeRight(-CAMERA_SPEED);
        if(dPressed)
            Camera.StrafeRight(CAMERA_SPEED);
        if(wPressed)
            Camera.MoveForward(-CAMERA_SPEED);
        if(sPressed)
            Camera.MoveForward(CAMERA_SPEED);
        if(ePressed)
            Camera.MoveUpward(CAMERA_SPEED);
        if(qPressed)
            Camera.MoveUpward(-CAMERA_SPEED);

        /* Draw Here */

        Camera.Render();

        /* Draw Cube */

        glPushMatrix();

        glTranslated(0.0,0.0,0.0);

        glColor3f(0.0,0.0,0.0);
        glLineWidth(4);
        //glutWireCube(1);
        glColor3f(0.0,0.3,1.0);
        glNormal3f(0.0,0.0,1.0);
        glutSolidCube(1);

        glPopMatrix();

        /* Draw Teapot */

        glPushMatrix();

        glTranslated(3.0,0.0,0.0);

        glColor3f(0.0,0.0,0.0);
        glLineWidth(4);
        glutWireTeapot(1);
        glColor3f(0.6,0.3,0.0);
        glutSolidTeapot(1);

        glPopMatrix();

        /* Draw Torus */

        glPushMatrix();

        glTranslated(-3.0,0.0,0.0);

        glColor3f(0.0,0.0,0.0);
        glLineWidth(4);
        glutWireTorus(0.25, 1, 16, 16);
        glColor3f(0.6,0.3,0.3);
        glutSolidTorus(0.25, 1, 16, 16);

        glPopMatrix();


        glfwSwapBuffers(Window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwDestroyWindow(Window);

    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `glut` functions without first calling `glutInit`.

```
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    ...
```

And also `glfwMakeContextCurrent(Window);` have to be called before any OpenGL functions.

For correct lighting, consider adjusting also your light direction (-1,-1,-1,0) would be better with your actual view matrix.

Comment: But there's maybe other errors in code you didn't supply (camera.cpp + hpp)

Comment: I think the `glutInit()` isn't even needed in this case. The OP is using glfw for the window and the context.  The typical implmentations of GLUT (both SGI's and freeglut) don't technically need the init  to use these object drawing functions.

Comment: @derhass: To have it working on my linux (freeglut), without `glutInit`, program stops with error explicitly requesting `glutInit`. It appears that both glfw and glut init are not conflicting...

Comment: OK, my bad than.  Ignore what I said, haven't checked thouroughly enough. However, I already gave you the +1 for the `makecurrent` one alone :)

Comment: Hi and thanks! It worked but now its all very dark. I don't know what is happening but it seems like the camera is moving with the light.

Comment: Make the changes in your matrices as Reto Koradi explains, it should solve this issue, also use glMaterial instead of glColor in lighted scene.

Answer (score 1):

`gluLookAt()` is used to build a **view** matrix. It therefore must be specified while you're in `GL_MODELVIEW` matrix mode. The sequence of calls for the initial transformation setup should be:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(90.0, (double)windowWidth / (double)windowHeight, 0.1, 100.0);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, -0.1, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
```

You can actually move this call sequence outside the event loop. There's no need to repeat it for each frame. Well, the `gluPerspective()` call depends on the window size, so you should repeat it when the window size changes. But it looks like you have the window size hardwired in your code.

You may also want to look into setting material properties with `glMaterialfv()`. The `glColor3f()` calls you're using for setting the color won't have the desired effect once you enable lighting.

And of course, as already pointed out in another answer, you need to call `glfwMakeContextCurrent()` **before** making any OpenGL calls.

I hope you're aware that most of the OpenGL features you're using are deprecated, and not available anymore in more recent versions of OpenGL (Core Profile, as well as OpenGL ES 2.0 and later).

Comment: combine Projection and camera(view) matrices in `GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX` doesn't sound bad to me, it gives you a clean identity model matrix to position your objects, but maybe I'm missing something. +1 for color considerations.

Comment: @j-p Lighting calculations are performed in eye coordinates, which is the coordinate system after the modelview transform has been applied. So if the view transformation is in the projection matrix, the result of the lighting calculations will be wrong.

Comment: thanks, I now understand some strange lighting errors of mine while testing old pipeline...

Comment: hmnn now it seems like it is in 2d. I think the problem is having two glLoadIdentitys.